# Éviter la juxtaposition de « plus »

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs

Il arrive que le mot *plus* soit utilisé dans ses deux sens au sein de la même phrase.

Exemples :

> Elle était plus riche que moi. Maintenant, elle n'est plus plus riche.
>
> J'avais plus de moutons que lui. À présent, je n'en ai plus plus.

Bien que sémantiquement correcte, la juxtaposition des deux *plus* est inélégante. On peut aisément transformer les phrases au cas par cas et éviter la juxtaposition, mais y a-t-il une tournure ou une astuce **générale** pour l'éviter ?

Comment: Le problème ne vient pas seulement de la juxtaposition de deux *plus*. « Elle était moins riche que moi. Maintenant, elle n'est plus moins riche ». Si je ne m'abuse, ça sonne tout autant faux.

Comment: Pourtant, « elle n'est pas plus riche » ne pose pas de problème.

Answer (score 9):

Pour tes deux exemples, je dirais

> ce n'est plus le cas

Je ne sais pas s'il existe des cas où ce n'est pas possible. Éventuellement on peut alors utiliser « plus davantage ». Ou simplement « moins ».

Comment: « Maintenant elle ne l'est plus ». Même idée, mais c'est tricher. Comment-faire s'il n'y a pas d'antécédent ? (sans le rajouter artificiellement)

Comment: @Stéphane _moins_ est le plus simple. _ne plus plus_ = _maintenant moins_

Answer (score 6):

Lorsque le cas d'égalité n'est pas important, la négation de *plus* est synonyme de la négation d'*autant*.

> Maintenant, elle n'est plus aussi riche.
>
> À présent, je n'en ai plus autant.

Ces formulations ont quand même une part d'ambiguité, entre « elle n'est plus aussi riche (qu'elle ne l'était avant) » et « elle n'est plus aussi riche (que je ne le suis maintenant) ».

On peut aussi tourner la phrase sans négation, en remplaçant *plus* par un adverbe tel que *désormais* ou *dorénavant*. Même *maintenant* ou *à présent* peuvent exprimer le fait qu'un état a changé entre le passé et le présent.

> Elle est désormais moins riche.
>
> J'en ai maintenant moins.

Answer (score 4):

On peut aussi contourner le problème en renversant la situation :

> Elle était plus riche que moi. Maintenant, je suis plus riche qu'elle.
>
> J'avais plus de moutons que lui. À présent, c'est lui qui en a plus.

Comme [le dit Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1174), le changement d'état sous-entendu par *ne plus* est de toutes façons suffisamment bien exprimé par *maintenant* ou *à présent*.

Answer (score 3):

Plusieurs possibilités sont ouvertes selon le sens que l'on veut obtenir:

> À présent je n'en ai plus autant

Sous entendu j'en ai moins.

> À présent c'est [cette situation] révolu/terminé.
>
> À présent c'est l'inverse/le contraire.

Answer (score 3):

On peut utiliser "ne mais", qui est un équivalent de "désormais ne plus".

> J'avais plus de moutons que lui. Je n'en ai mais plus.

C'est peu usité, mais plus succinct, et si cela peut paraître vieillot, cela peut éventuellement lancer la conversation sur des aspects linguistiques.

Comment: _[Mais](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mais)_ comme adverbe est quand même noté comme _vieux_, et franchement je ne l'avais jamais entendu.

Comment: Ben oui. Faut choisir entre une vielle tournure propre, et des magouilles "modernes". :)